# mootools table pushmany

Tags: javascript, mootools, html-table

I'm trying to build a table using the Mootools HMTLTable class, specifically using the pushMany method.

I have built a sample using the same syntax that they show in the docs at http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/HtmlTable#HtmlTable:pushMany, but I can't get the data to display. Is there somethign obvious I'm missing?

Thanks

A fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/W2nMn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an error in the docs, you should just use `myTable.pushMany`

http://jsfiddle.net/W2nMn/2/